# How to resolve a crack in the shower floor?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, tile, plastic

My dad did a great job renewing his bathroom, but sadly a crack has appeared on the shower's plastic floor base.

He believes the crack has developed because he installed it on top of wooden beams rather than cement.

**Is there a work-around to fix this, or is it a case of ripping it out and starting again?**

Here is a picture of the shower (the crack is located underneath where the mat has been placed):

[image: Shower image]

Comment: Actually, a picture of the actual crack itself would help :) Also, nice shower!

Comment: @alt Sorry, I don't have a close-up of the crack at the moment. Any advice you can give without this picture? And yeah, it is a nice shower - it would be a shame to rip it all out and start again.

Comment: Depending on the material the pan is made from, it may be possible to patch the crack. However, if there isn't proper support under the pan, this crack or other cracks will likely reappear.

Comment: I recently purchased a home which had a crack in the bottom of the fiberglass tub/shower. After scouting around, I found that I could either order a fiberglass patch kit (comes with fiberglass cloth + epoxy) or use some simple JB weld epoxy (the kind that works with fiberglass). I chose the latter since it was readily available at the local hardware store. It doesn't match the tub color, so I'll have to find a paint to cover it with, but it seems to be holding the crack together, so far. The support beneath the crack is not that great though, so I know eventually I'll have to replace the tub.